# Issue with the text Alignment in android 8 (oreo) - extra spaces are added in between two words

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing a weird issue for text alignment on Android OREO (8) while for other Android OS version the text looks good, the OREO text is converting all the spaces to tabs automatically.

Have anyone faced the issue likewise, or can anyone suggest the solution?

Below is my XML markup for the control:

**EditText used to take Input**,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/AddressFirstLine_add1_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:maxLength="64"
        android:textColorHint="@color/md_grey_200"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"/>
```

**Displaying Textview**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_full_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/md_grey_200"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"/>
```

I am attaching the screenshot for both Android api version 6(marshmallow) and 8(oreo).

**Version 6**

[image: look good in android version 6 (Marshmallow)]

**Version 8**

[image: instead of single space tab is added in version 8 (oreo)]

Comment: This is a font style problem because not all font styles in the Oreo version have been supported correctly

Comment: it is not a font issue i have tried changing the font but the issue still persist